# The following classes could not be instantiated: - androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

I just recovered a project, which was broken by Android Studio (crashed and overwrote all files except for MainActivity). I used parts of my old backup of V1.0 (currently at V3.1) and recovered some code with an app (Show Java). The problem is that all occurences of the constraintLayout are showing as grey boxes. I am using

```
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
```

I have googled it already and haven't found a solution, which would work out for me.

**Example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/reset_game_disclaimer"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:text="@string/reset_game_are_you_sure"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="0"/>

    <Button
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/button_reset_game"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:text="@string/reset_game"
        android:backgroundTint="#ffb00020"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reset_game_disclaimer"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.705"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Stracktrace**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/constraintlayout/widget/R$styleable
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.init(ConstraintLayout.java:599)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:576)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:403)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:186)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:144)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:418)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:429)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:323)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:200)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:572)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:698)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Try to upgrade it to latest version. Besides this upgrade your project to **AndroidX**

Comment: For further investigation can you add your `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to upgrade the dependency to latest version. Also upgrade your project to **AndroidX**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4"
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817015/2637449) to upgrade your project to **AndroidX**.

Comment: My project was already migrated to AndroidX and the dependency above worked, except for layout files having a transparent background. How do I fix that?